# How to disable prettier adding {" "} in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

I have got a problem with prettier's formatting, which when I'm saving the code, it will add annoying `{" "}` to some parts of the `jsx` code e.g.:

[image]

I've searched about how to fix this issue, but couldn't find any solution, can anybody help on this?

Here is the reprex: [prettier playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#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)
and here is the related [issue on github](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223)

Comment: you should probably just remove the extra whitespace. doesn't seem like there's a way to achieve that in prettier.

Comment: manually removing those are really annoying, there should be a better solution.

Comment: you could always do a find and replace. prettier has limited configuration available, it is an opinionated code formatted. your best bet would be to look at another formatter.

Comment: I think (*IDK, could be wrong*) nullptr meant not leaving the whitespace in your code to begin with so any auto-formatters aren't converting them to `{" "}` to be rendered. Go to "View -> Render Whitespace" and toggle this and you can see what whitespace characters you have just hanging around and remove the extraneous trailing whitespace. You could also find a different  formatter as nullptr says.

Comment: There are also settings in the editor to trim trailing whitespace.

Comment: I think That's a problem and should be fixed, not just changing the formatter...

Comment: The problem is that **prettier** is a really restrictive prettiefier. Its idea is that it behaves exactly the same in every project with just a few limited configuration options. This means you either like their design decisions or you shouldn't use that tool. I personally went away from using it due to that.

Comment: the only problem with `prettier` which I've ever had was this annoying useless `{" "}`, And I don't know how to fix it

Comment: this seems more of a you problem tbh, just remove trailing whitespace when you code. If this was not a thing, you'd have other issues like `a <span>bc</span>` rendering to `abc` instead of `a bc`. So it's hardly useless.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that's not an option for me. I am looking specifically for a solution that obviously wouldn't need any manual intervention like what you kindly proposed. So I guess I'll wait to see if someone else has a better idea/solution/workaround.

Comment: Please read the thread you linked, specifically the one that links to ["Option Philosophy · Prettier"](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). tl;dr Prettier is opinionated and doesn't add options any more. Some were added in the past to make the project more popular, some were added due to compatibility reasons, and some were added "after 'great demand.' ". Some options they regret adding but won't removed because of difficulty "Difficult to remove now, these options exist as a historical artifact and should not motivate adding more options"

Comment: This is desired behavior. If you type something like `<br /> <span>...long text...</span>` then that space is significant. Prettier doesn't know you don't care about the space. When prettier formats, the line break doesn't preserve a space between those elements, so you need either `&nbsp;` or `{' '}` to preserve it. I agree this is a you problem, don't type a space between elements unless you want one. It's a habit I haven't seen anyone else have.

Comment: @AndyRay  Thanks for the time to explain, but I think it can reserve one space instead of adding `{" "}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is an issue about this on [prettier's GitHub](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223) , and it has been closed without any practical solution, So this question does not have any practical answer. The only answer which has been mentioned in that github issue is just use `//prettier-ignore` that will *disable* it:

Default version:

```
/*source*/
<p>hello <a href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a> world</p>


/*output*/
<p>
  hello{" "}
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    LINK
  </a>{" "}
  world
</p>;
```

Using `//prettier-ignore` to disable it:

```
/*source*/

//prettier-ignore
<p>hello <a href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a> world</p>


/*output:*/

//prettier-ignore
<p>hello <a href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a> world</p>
```

Here is the [playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#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)